# Collatz optimization

Tags: programming, performance-tuning, project-euler

I'm VERY new to Mathematica programming (and by new I mean two days), and was solving Project Euler question 12, which states:

> Which starting number, under one million, produces the longest [Collatz] chain?

Now don't take this question wrong. **I am not asking for a solution, I am simply wondering why my proposed solution is taking so long to produce an answer. It does eventually produce the correct solution to the problem.**

My code is below:

```
collatzLength[x_] := Module[{c, n}, (For[n = x; c = 1, n != 1, c += 1, 
    If[EvenQ[n], n = n/2, n = 3*n + 1]]); c]
Last@Flatten@(MaximalBy[Transpose@{(collatzLength /@ 
     Range[1000000]), Range[1000000]}, First])
```

It seems that the `collatzLength /@ Range[1000000]` is what is taking so long, so I am wondering how I can improve the collatz function (or any of the code) so that it completes in a reasonable timeframe.

Comment: many more collatz algorithmic ideas [here](https://vzn1.wordpress.com/code/collatz-conjecture-experiments/), & hope to hear from others in [chat]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You´ll find a lot of Mathematica Code on the internet regarding this problem. Your code generates the collate sequence for every number without taking into account, that there are a lot of duplicate calculations. You can approach it via

```
collatz[n_] := collatz[n] = If[EvenQ[n], n/2, 3*n + 1]
```

to remember the calculations, then...

```
collatzSequence[n_] := NestWhileList[collatz, n, #1 > 1 &]
```

and

```
Length /@ (collatzSequence /@ Range[2, 1000000]) // Max
```

to calculate.

Speed could be improved by compiling the definition of `collatz`

Comment: Can you extend memoization for example to parametrized version `collatz[a_,b_][n_]` where `{a,b}` generalize `{3,1}`?

Comment: Also, might as well divide `3*n + 1` by 2, saves redundant steps.

Comment: @ alancalvitti: A "quick and dirty" approach can be:collatz[args_] := 
 collatz[args] = 
  With[{a = args[[1]], b = args[[2]], n = args[[3]]}, 
   If[EvenQ[n], {a, b, n/2}, {a, b, a*n + b}]
   ] and then collatzSequence[args_] := 
 NestWhileList[collatz, args, Last[#] > 1 &, 10, 1000]. I terminated the NesstWhileList for security reasons. The tripple {5,1,17} has more than 1000 Iterates ;-).

Comment: .... sorry the code is not shown very pretty, but readable ...

Comment: some more detailed non-mathematica description of what this is doing (memoization? how so?) would be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

For extra brute force, just `Compile` it to C code:

```
collatzLength = 
 Compile[{{x, _Integer}}, 
  Module[{c, 
    n}, (For[n = x; c = 1, n != 1, c += 1, 
     If[EvenQ[n], n = Round[n/2], n = 3*n + 1]]); c], 
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]
```

It computes the first million lengths in under 2 seconds:

```
First@AbsoluteTiming@collatzLength[Range[1000000]]
(*1.248002*)
```

For more info on what functions are compilable, see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions).

Answer (score 6):

Your `collatzLength` function is fast on an individual integer, but when you map it to all integers from 1 to a million, the function recalculates values repeatedly. For example, the Collatz series for $n=10$ is $\{10,5,16,8,4,2,1\}$. But the length for $n=5$ would have been already calculated to be 6. Hence, the Collatz length for $n=10$ is $1+6=7$. Use memoization to store previous values. For example,

```
CollatzLength[1]:=1
CollatzLength[n_]:=(CollatzLength[n]=...)/;EvenQ[n]
CollatzLength[n_]:=(CollatzLength[n]=...)/;OddQ[n]
```

Your challenge is to fill in the blanks above with code referring to previously calculated values (smaller `n`). The speed is vastly improved at the cost of storing the million definitions of `CollatzLength[n]` for specific `n`.

Comment: I added `If[KeyExistsQ[collatzValues, n], collatzValues[n], 
 collatzValues[n] =  1 + collatzLength[n/2]]` between the brackets of Collatz...EvenQ, and `If[KeyExistsQ[collatzValues, n], collatzValues[n], 
 collatzValues[n] = 1 + collatzLength[n*3 + 1]]` between the Brackets of OddQ, and added an association called `collatzValues`. Is that the kind of thing you meant?

Comment: @globby  Yes, looks good. Try it and see!