# Function to list Collatz sequence doesn`t work

Tags: functions, function-construction

I am new to *Mathematica* and was trying to make a function that lists the Collatz sequence stating with a given number, but I can´t get it to work. Here is my function:

```
collatz[x_] := NestWhileList[If[Mod[x, 2] == 0, x/2, x*3 + 1], x, x != 1]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=collatz

Answer (score 3):

`x` is just your starting value for the iteration. The function to apply, and the stopping condition, should both be applied to the *current value* obtained by the iteration, and are probably best expressed using pure functions:

```
collatz[x_] := NestWhileList[If[Mod[#, 2] == 0, #/2, #*3 + 1] &, x, # != 1 &]

collatz[5]
(* Out: {5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1} *)
```

This topic has been discussed in some detail on MMA.SE. You could start here: [Collatz optimization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69902/27951)

Comment: You beat me by a about a minute :)

Comment: @m_goldberg :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need anonymous functions. The way it's written currently will replace every instance of `x` on the right hand side with the number you provide as the argument for `collatz`. What you want is something which can act on the value produced by `NestWhileList` on each iteration. So use

```
Clear[collatz]
collatz[x_] :=NestWhileList[If[Mod[#, 2] == 0, #/2, #*3 + 1]&, x, # != 1&]
```

What's happening here is that the `&` tells the MMA interpreter that everything preceeding it is an anonymous (or inline) function and the `#` will all be replaced by the first argument of that anonymous function. To make it more general,

```
NestWhileList[f[#]&,x,g[#]&]
```

`NestWhileList` applies `f` to `x` on the first iteration and evaluates `f[x]`. Next it applies `g` and expects a Boolean results so if `g[f[x]]` is `False` it stops. If `True` it goes on to the next iteration, now applying `f` again to the previous result, evaluating now `f[f[x]]` and continues until `g[f[...f[x]...]` evaluates false.