# A Simplistic C# (.NET) Reloader

Tags: performance-tuning, .netlink

Can one write a very straightforward C# reloader akin to this [Java reloader](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6144/looking-for-longest-common-substring-solution/6376#6376), that enables *Mathematica*-like usage of functions from existing C# code in string format, in an easy and elegant fashion directly in *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possible to write such a code and I will present the code and sample usage below. The motivation for this question/answer is [this Java reloader by Leonid Shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6144/looking-for-longest-common-substring-solution/6376#6376) and I borrowed some code from his answer.

### Simplistic C# Reloader

The code below is a C# reloader. It takes a string of C# code and (optionally) a C# compiler path, attempts a compile and if the compilation succeeds it calls on `NETLink` to load the `DLL`. It also takes the same `Option`s as `LoadNETType`, making it easy to choose how you want the loaded functions to appear.

#### Code

```
BeginPackage["DotNETReloader`", {"NETLink`"}];

dotNETLoader::usage =
 "dotNETLoader[code_, compilerPath_] takes a C# code in string format
and (optionally) a C# compiler path, it then attempts to compile the
string code into a .NET dll suitable for use with NETLink"

dotNETLoader::dirmakeerr = "Can not create directory `1`";
dotNETLoader::invst = "The loader is not in a valid state. Perhaps some temporary
directories do not exist or could not be created";
dotNETLoader::cmperr = "The following compilation errors were encountered: \n`1`";

Options[dotNETLoader] = Options[LoadNETType]

Begin["`Private`"]    

$stateValidQ = True;
$csc = If[$SystemID === "Windows-x86-64", "csc.exe", "mcs"];
$err = If[$SystemID === "Windows-x86-64", 2, 3];
$tempDirectory = FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Temp", "dotNET"}];

(* If a namespace exists, get the name *)
getNamespace[code_String] := 
 With[{ns = 
    StringCases[code, "namespace" ~~ Whitespace ~~ name : (WordCharacter ..) :> name]},
    First @ ns /; ns =!= {}]

(* Get the class name *)
getClass[classCode_String] := 
 With[{cl = 
    StringCases[classCode, 
    "public" ~~ Whitespace | (Whitespace ~~ "static" ~~ Whitespace) ~~
    "class" | "struct" | "interface" ~~ Whitespace ~~ 
     name : (WordCharacter ..) :> name]}, First @ cl /; cl =!= {}]

getClass[__] := Throw[$Failed, error[getClass]];

If[!FileExistsQ[#] && CreateDirectory[#] === $Failed, 
   Message[dotNETLoader::dirmakeerr, #]; $stateValidQ = False;] &@$tempDirectory

dotNETLoader[code_String, compiler_String: $csc, 
   opts : OptionsPattern[]] /; $stateValidQ :=
 Module[{sourcePath, run, 
   options = FilterRules[{opts}, Options[dotNETLoader]],
   namespace = getNamespace[code], className = getClass[code]},
  sourcePath = FileNameJoin[{$tempDirectory, className <> ".cs"}];
  Export[sourcePath, code, "String"];
  run = RunProcess[{compiler, "-t:library", "-optimize+", sourcePath}, 
    ProcessDirectory -> $tempDirectory];
  If[run[[1]] =!= 0, Message[dotNETLoader::cmperr,
    Style[#, Red]& @ run[[$err]]]; $Failed,
      ReinstallNET[];
   LoadNETAssembly @ FileNameJoin[{$tempDirectory, className <> ".dll"}];
   If[Head @ namespace =!= getNamespace, 
    LoadNETType[namespace <> "." <> className, options], 
    LoadNETType[className, options]]
   ]
  ]

dotNETLoader[_String] := CompoundExpression[Message[dotNETLoader::invst]; $Failed]

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

#### Notes

I have tested this code successfully on both **Windows** and **Linux** and would appreciate it if someone that has a Mac can also test it on **MacOS** (I won't be able to do this but I expect it to work unaltered since the .NET platform and C# compiler are available via **Mono**). Also, please I will like others to test this code and provide feedback on all platforms. You will notice that I have named the function `dotNETLoader` instead of `cSharpLoader`, this is because I'm planning on extending this function to include `F#` (which I have successfully tested on Windows) and possibly, other .NET languages.

Due to my usage of `RunProcess` to avoid bringing up the console in Windows, this will only work on *Mathematica* 10 and above versions.

The package works by saving the C# string code and saving it as a `.cs` file in a temporary directory and using the New in 10 function `RunProcess` to invoke your installed C# compiler to compile the class into a .NET library `.dll` file. It then calls `NETLink` to load the library and make the functions available for use in *Mathematica*.

#### Usage

I will show some examples of how to use this package. Let's start by borrowing some C# codes from the web and saving them as strings.

```
code1 = 

"public class LCS{  
     public static string longestCommonSubstring(string s1, string s2) 
     {
          int Start = 0;
          int Max = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++){
             for (int j = 0; j < s2.Length; j++){
                int x = 0;
                while (s1[i + x] == s2[j + x]){
                   x++;
                   if (((i + x) >= s1.Length || ((j + x) >= s2.Length))) 
                      break;
                }
                if (x > Max) {
                   Max = x;
                   Start = i;
                }
             }
          }
          return s1.Substring(Start, Max);
     }
  }";
```

This code is the C# equivalent of the 2nd code [from here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#Java) (There are only a few differences but it took less than a minute to make the changes to C# code)

First we load the package:

```
Needs["DotNETReloader`"]
```

Now we load the function using `dotNETLoader`:

```
dotNETLoader[code1, StaticsVisible -> True]
```

> `NETType["LCS", 1]`

We can see the possible options:

```
Options[dotNETLoader]
```

> `{StaticsVisible -> False, AllowShortContext -> True}`

Setting `StaticsVisible` to `True` enables us to call the function directly without the class name and makes it feel like a built-in function.

```
longestCommonSubstring["AAABBBBCCCCC","CCCBBBAAABABA"]
```

> `"AAAB"`

I'll add the same benchmark Leonid used in his Java reloader just to show that in some cases it may be better to use C#:

```
s1 = StringJoin@RandomChoice[{"A", "C", "T", "G"}, 10000];
s2 = StringJoin@RandomChoice[{"A", "C", "T", "G"}, 10000];
```

Here we use the Mathematica's built-in function `LongestCommonSubsequence`:

```
LongestCommonSubsequence[s1, s2] // RepeatedTiming
```

> `{0.25, "GTCCCTCACACTG"}`

And here is our loaded C# function:

```
longestCommonSubstring[s1, s2] // RepeatedTiming
```

> `{0.35, "GTCCCTCACACTG"}`

This [collatz optimization question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69902/collatz-optimization) is interesting, so I decided to see how our new C# reloader can help us here. I found this code online a while ago (can't remember where) and made just one simple change to parallelize it.

```
code2 = 

"using System.Threading.Tasks; 

 namespace Tester
 {
     public struct Calc
     {
        public static int[] ParallelCollatz(int[] list)
         {
             Parallel.For(0, list.Length, i =>
             {
                 int count;
                 long k = list[i];
                 for (count = 1; k != 1; count++)
                 {
                     k = ((k & 1) == 0) ? k / 2 : 3 * k + 1;
                 }
                 list[i] = count;
             });

             return list;
         }
    }

 }";
```

As before (load the package if not already loaded), we load the function using `dotNETLoader`

```
dotNETLoader[code2, StaticsVisible -> True]
```

> `NETType["Tester.Calc", 2]`

I wanted to point out a few things about the package with this example. First, notice that the type is `Tester.Calc` instead of just `Calc`, this is becaude this class was placed in a namespace, but the reloader notices this and takes care of it for us. Secondly, the way we use the feature in conjuction with built-in *Mathematica* functions to solve the problem shows how natural the approach becomes. Finally, this will also work for `structs` as well as static classes. Back to the example:

```
int = Range[1*^6];   

(* Here ParallelCollatz is the loaded C# function *)

RepeatedTiming @ Ordering[ParallelCollatz @ int, -1]
```

> `{0.0610, {837799}}`

I will compare this to the compiled-to-C function provided by DumpsterDoofus.

```
Ordering[collatzLength @ int, -1] // RepeatedTiming
```

> `{0.877, {837799}}`

#### Summary

We see that this C# Reloader can be quite useful and fits naturally into the *Mathematica*-style usage scenario. In the first example the highly optimized built in function was only slightly faster than our borrowed-from-web code. What's interesting from my testing so far is that there's not much performance difference when using these functions on both Windows and Linux. For the second example where I compared brute force approaches, we see that the loaded function was over a magnitude faster.

Comment: What if `Parallelization -> True` is added to `collatzLength`?

Comment: @xzczd, I tried it and it was actually slower. `0.978` seconds. From my experience once you have the `Listable` attribute, adding parallelization is pointless for compilation.

Comment: OK, seems that the parallelization functionality of _Mathematica_ is really a bit out of date…