# Collatz Conjecture

Tags: programming, procedural-programming

By definition of [`Collatz Conjecture`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) or $3n+1$, regardless of the sequence (ie.$ m1,m2,m3....mn$), at the end, it eventually produces 1 at the end. For example, if you let $m=10$ (ie. $10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1...$), you must repeat 6 times and eventually reach to 1.

How can **Module**

```
Collatz[m_]:= Module[{...}]
```

be used that takes **positive integer** $m$ and outputs the "number of times" that the procedure must be repeated until obtaining 1?

**Side Note**: Although the [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69902/collatz-optimization) does incorporate the Module function, It's not about longest [Collatz] chain.

Comment: It can be done as a straightforward loop. Not necessarily the best way, but reasonably effective. `Collatz[m_] := 
 Module[{j = 0, m1 = m}, 
  While[m1 =!= 1, j++; m1 = If[OddQ[m1], 3*m1 + 1, m1/2]]; j]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recursion comes in handy here:

```
Collatz[m_] := Collatz[m] = 1 + If[EvenQ[m], Collatz[m/2], Collatz[3 m + 1]];
Collatz[1] := 0;
Collatz[10] 
(* 6 *)
```

Comment: +1 Recommend that definition start off as `Collatz[m_Integer?Positive] :=...`